# Problem with aws expiration time for presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, pre-signed-url

I have created a function to get a link to download an object in S3.

```
def get_presigned_url(s3_bucket, s3_object_key, expiration_seconds):
     url = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),                      
                        aws_access_key_id='access_key_id',
                        aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key').generate_presigned_url(
                        ClientMethod='get_object',
                        Params={'Bucket': s3_bucket, 'Key': s3_object_key},
                        ExpiresIn=expiration_seconds)
     return url
```

It creates the link with the correct expiry time (90 hours) but after 20 hours the link stops working.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is your code running? Is it on your own computer, or on an Amazon EC2 instance? Where is the Access Key and Secret Key coming from -- does it belong to an IAM User and does it start with `AKIA`? Why are you passing-in the Access Key and Secret Key rather than simply letting boto3 retrieve the credentials from the `~/.aws/credentials` file (or from an IAM Role if it is running on an EC2 instance)?

Comment: The code is running in a EC2 instance.
The Access Key and Secret Key come from the IAM User (start with AKIA)
I can use the ´~/.aws/credentials´ file but it has the same keys

Comment: When you look at the pre-signed URL, can you see an Access Key in the parameters? Does it match the IAM User Access Key (starting with `AKIA`)?

Comment: I am looking at the URL and you are right it generates it with ASIA instead of AKIA can you give me some clue where the problem comes from.

Comment: It is using temporary credentials (`ASIA`) rather than permanent credentials (`AKIA`) to generate the pre-signed URL. Are you literally passing a string like `aws_access_key_id='AKIAxxx'?

Comment: Yes I'm using AKIA as aws_access_key_id

Answer (score 1):

PreSigned URL created using

1. Console: 1 minute and 12 hours max
2. AWS CLI or AWS SDKs - max 7 days

If you created a presigned URL by using a temporary token, then the URL expires when the token expires, even if you created the URL with a later expiration time.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#PresignedUrl-Expiration

Alternatively, override the session and create a client using that session as below

```
import boto3.session
session = boto3.session.Session(
                  region_name='us-east-1', 
                  aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id', 
                  aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key')

s3_client = session.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
                    ClientMethod='get_object',
                    Params={'Bucket': s3_bucket, 'Key': s3_object_key},
                    ExpiresIn=expiration_seconds)
```

Comment: I'm using the AWS SDK, boto3, even so I think the maximum time is set to 12 hours. And in the above code I think that there isn't any temporary token

Comment: what is the value you passed in seconds? 324000?

Comment: Yes, I print it before the function

Comment: @CrashingTurttles Try using the alternative solutions to override session. This is just to be sure that session is created using passed creds instead of EC2 instance profile

Comment: It's not working I'm getting the ASIA instead of the AKIA to access the link.

Comment: How, did you use "session.client" while creating client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening with your code, but here is a sample Python program based on your code:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),                      
    aws_access_key_id='AKIA123',
    aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key'
)

url = client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': 'my-bucket', 'Key': 'my-key'},
    ExpiresIn=900
)

print(url)
```

The output is:

> https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-key?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA123%2F20230630%2Fap-southeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230630T121331Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b9b161e89ad21f63d829b56240cecc5985d149608cc4fc152ae23dc46c38ef3f

You'll notice that is is displaying the *EXACT* Access Key that was passed into the function (`AKIA123`). Generating a pre-signed URL does not actually involve making a call to AWS. Rather, it is just using a hash function and the Secret Key to 'sign' the request.

Yet, strangely, your code is returning an `ASIA` key. I think you are not running the code you have shown us. Try running the above code and you'll see.